# spring collection implementation of injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, collections, implementation

I am kinda new to Spring.

My Springframework version is 5.3.9.

What specific implementation does Spring choose to be injected?

for example I have

```
// bean class

private Map<String,String> myMap;

public void setMyMap(Map<String, String> myMap) {
    this.myMap = myMap;
}
```

```
<!-- bean def xml -->
<bean id="student" class="com.my.bean.Student">
    <property name="myMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="name" value="someName"/>
            <entry key="school" value="someSchool"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Questions:

- Does Spring choose HashMap as implementation to be injected? Or Other implementation?
- Does Spring allow choose of implementation class
- Suppose the default implementation class will change with versions where could I find docs about this.

Many Thanks

My Efforts:

- I read the spring-framewwork5.x doc and searched for collection implementation class but failed to find it.
- I also try to read the spring-framework5.x sourcecode `org.springframework.beans.factory.supportDefaultListableBeanFactory#resolveMultipleBeans` But still fail to find the implementation class.
- My Java is not excellent
- Googled about it but didn't find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [Spring 5.3.9 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/html/core.html#xsd-schemas-util-map) it stated that

> You can also explicitly control the exact type of Map that is instantiated and populated by using the 'map-class' attribute on the <util:map/> element.

Example:

```
<util:map id="emails" map-class="java.util.TreeMap">
    <entry key="pechorin" value="pechorin@hero.org"/>
    <entry key="raskolnikov" value="raskolnikov@slums.org"/>
    <entry key="stavrogin" value="stavrogin@gov.org"/>
    <entry key="porfiry" value="porfiry@gov.org"/>
</util:map>
```

They don't state the default implementation, it's only stated that:

> If no 'map-class' attribute is supplied, the container chooses a Map implementation.

I'd suggest printing your map class name to figure out the default type.